# Whats happens to an open asio tcp socket when the service is stopped and restarted?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

**Short Version:** If I have an open tcp socket running in an ioserive what happens if I stop the service? Should data continue to queue in the tcp socket (assuming the server continues to send data and there has been no disconnect)? If so can I retrieve that data by resetting and restarting the ioserive?

**Long Version:** I'm trying to put a blocking interface around my asio based tcp socket API.

The user initially connects using the API which opens a socket to a server.

For each subsequent API call the ioservice is reset and started, then data is sent to the server using the tcp socket with boost::asio::write and a response waited on. The response from the server is handled using async_read_until. When the response is received the handler is invoked, the ioservice stopped and the original blocking API call releases back to the client, with the data from the server. This works OK for request-response type commands. In summary:

- API blocking call
- ioservice resets and starts
- tcp packet sent to server
- server responds
- handler invoked
- ioservice stopped
- API call released and data passed to user

Another command is a request-response that starts a broadcast from the server that updates an internal cache on the client-side. The idea is that the user accesses this cache with another API function after an initial attempt to refresh it using an ioservice start-stop process similar to above. However, before this attempt the code checks to see if any data is available on the socket using one of the options below:

```
  bool is_data_available() {
    //boost::asio::socket_base::bytes_readable command(true);
    //socket_->io_control(command);
    //return command.get() > 0;
      return socket_->available() > 0;
  }
```

There is never any data, even though the server has logged as having sent the data.

So summary for the broadcast:

- Successfully executes the previous list of bullet points to start the broadcasting
- Observe that the server has sent the data
- Call above code block to see if any data in the socket (note that the service has not been started at this point)
- Never any data

Comment: You could test it with a small tcp server in python or C++, which will definetly cause a disconnect error if the `io_service` restart would cause a new initialization of the socket. I think this won't be the case, but I am not 100% sure.